# Change lead status to 'Closed - Converted' without creating an opportunity, account and contact

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

I am manually creating opportunity from lead and changing lead status as 'Closed - Converted'. I can prevent opportunity creation using setDoNotCreateOpportunity(Boolean) method. but there is no method  available for account and contact. Is there any way to prevent creation of account and contact while converting lead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on the conversion screen at the account interaction section make sure you're selecting 'Attach to existing' instead of 'Create new' in the dropdown. Then just use the magnifying glass to select which exact account you'd like to merge into. Then proceed and you'll be presented with a contact merge screen as well, so you won't have to create a duplicate contact. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use Database.LeadConvert.setAccountId and Database.LeadConvert.setContactId to link to an existing Account and Contact. You must either link to an existing record, or create a new record. There is no option to simply set the Lead Status to a Converted value without either of these paths.